# Erasing apache2 access log from within a PHP script

Tags: php, apache, apache2

I have my apache2 generate an access.log file, which is owned by root:root (I can change this if required/possible).

I can access the file with apache2, as in `file_get_contents('../access.log');`

In some cases, using CRON, I need to reset the contents of this file, that is erase it and start gathering only new data.

However, when I erase the file, apache doesn't create it again.

How can I do this?

Comment: What happens if you leave the file in place but overwrite it with an empty string?

Comment: I think that's a solution. Can I do that with ``file_put_contents``? I need to use PHP for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the script has privileges to delete the file, you should also be able to write to it:

`file_put_contents($filename, "");` will overwrite the file with an empty string without deleting it. There's probably a "right" way to get apache to recreate the log file, but this should be a functional workaround.